# How to get the rating in primefaces 5?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF 2 application that uses **PrimeFaces 5**, particularly the `<p:rating/>` component. In the view, the component is declared like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="avaliacao" rendered="#{meuContexto.avaliacaoPagina==null}">
    <div class="float-right">
    <p:rating value="#{meuContexto.avaliacaoPagina}" cancel="false">
        <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{meuContexto.onAvaliarPagina}" update="avaliacao" />
    </p:rating>
    </div>
    Você ainda não deu sua opinião sobre esta página. Quando tiver uma opinião, não deixe de registrá-la!
    <div class="float-clear"></div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The idea is tho ask for a rating only if no one exists (`meuContexto.onAvaliarPagina()==null`) so far. When the user clicks the star, the rating should be set and user continues to work, without any page load.

The messages here are not important. The `<p:rating/>` component is located in a left-floating `<div/>` just to satisfy the layout. The method to be notified when a star is clicked is like this:

```
public void onAvaliarPagina(RateEvent rateEvent) {
    avaliacao.setNota((Integer)rateEvent.getRating());
}
```

So, my expectation is that when one of the stars is clicked, the `meuContexto.onAvaliarPagina()` method is called and `rateEvent.getRating()` should contain the number of the star, but I always receive the precise value that is retuned by `meuContexto.getAvaliacaoPagina()`.

What do I have to do in order to receive in `meuContexto.onAvaliarPagina()` the actual rating set by the user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just after I posted the question I noiticed that the component wasn't inside a form. So, this was causing the problem.

I'll let the question and the answer here just in case someone else runs in the same situation!